# Cannot add multiple basemaps at once using Python console of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, arcgis-online-basemaps, qgis-python-console

I am using Qgis 3.8. I want to download a bunch of basemaps to have easy access to in the future. I tried using python console with URl: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py. 
I get this error message:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what did you copy in console?

Comment: I copied the URL in my message above into python console.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Please present the code on your Python script within your question.

Comment: first copy sources=[] in console and then the loop

Answer (score 1):

You just copy and paste the text from the file you linked into the QGIS Python console and hit enter. Don't paste the url into the console.